# Multiple Dropdowns

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

How to handle multiple dropdowns?how to store it in a list of web elements

```java
Select select=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[starts-with(@data-sor-id,'quo_sor_price_sor_id_')]")));
```

If i write this i receive list of 8 dropdowns.When i type this xpath to match with elements i get this [When i put the xpath to match with elements in GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IKxm.png)

I want to handle these dropdowns dynamically using loop
[This is the pictures of dropdowns which gets created at the run time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAN31.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to process the selects returned by the XPath you mention, would something like this help?

```java
List<WebElement> selects = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[starts-with(@data-sor-id,'quo_sor_price_sor_id_')]"));
for (WebElement we : selects) {
    Select s = new Select(we);
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

Or do you need special treatment for particular instances?

Comment: thank you @kidney for your response.My puspose is to select the first dropdown and click the first option,and then select the second dropdown and click the  first option and so on. and for that if i write code s.selectByIndex(0); it is not able to select any option and gives exception element not interactable.Am i going wrong anywhere ?Many thanks in advance

Comment: This is difficult to tell without knowing the page. If the select itself is not interactable, maybe there is a loading mask or something covering it. You may try adding an explicit wait. Also, if the select has some special javascript-based features, plain `selectByIndex` may not work...

Comment: my experience says, it gives not interactable exception at that time when the code is trying to point to one element but the xpath returns more than one element,like i have mentioned it is returning 8 elements(8 dropdowns)  https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IKxm.png .But when i choose particular dropdown's id and selectByIndex ,it works. for example  Select JT1=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("dd_surveySOR1_xpath=//select[@data-sor-id='quo_sor_price_sor_id_1']")));
   JT1.selectByIndex(0);

Comment: If it would have been a text box or any other element i can receive it in a list of web elements and use the those elements with index number for example

List <WebElement> textBoxes=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@name,'quo_sor_unit_price_')]"));
textBoxes.get(0).sendKeys("xyz"); 
so this will choose the first text box.Can i do same with with a list of dropdowns .Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it should be possible. That is basically what my example code does - goes through the individual selects and uses them. So you can give it a try and see...